# Android: How to communicate between non-ui threads and processes the data on the caller thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

**The Problem:**

I need to pass an indication\object to thread B from thread A, and that indication needs to be processed on thread A asynchronously (with not blocking).

**Background:**

I Have designed an **SDK (thread B)** which basically run some tasks via a ThreadPoolExecutor mechanism.
the **3rd party app (thread A)** that uses the SDK requests to run a task and impl. a callback for the result, tasks can operate in parallel and return the result asynchronously.

i.e. a request snippet:

```
SDK.taskA(new CustomCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onFinish(String s) {
         // run some code - let's refer to as **Section A**
    }
});
```

i.e SDK returns a callback:

```
mCustomCallback.onFinish(String s);
```

The problem lays in the face that the callback - "onFinish" is proccessed on the worker thread - SDK (obviously) and not on the caller thread. i.e. if the caller thread (A) id is 400 and the worker (B) is 500, i need that "onFinish" will be called on thread 400.

i have tried different solution but non of them matches my requirements:

1. Handlers - handler seems to be the obvious solution but having to manage and observe that Looper.prepare will be called only once per thread is tricky, what if the 3rd party app already defined a handler for the calling thread in his app for his own purposes ?  or what if he start numerous different SDK tasks from a single thread ? this requires to start handling the Looper state for each thread checking if it exists or not.
2. LocalBrodcastReceivers - return indication only to the UI-Thread
3. Callback - passing an interface, return indication on the worker thread (B).
4. Shared Memory - requires that the the caller thread (A) is blocked until an indication is received from the worker Thread (B)
5. - Pipes - requires that the the caller thread (A) is blocked until an indication is received from the worker Thread (B)

the purpose behind this design is that i cannot predict the amount of work that the 3rd party app will preform on the callback from the SDK so i do not want it to happen on one of my thread pool workers.

in addition i am specifically talking about 2 non-ui threads due to the fact that is one of them was the ui thread there are many good solutions out there.

Any Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), Its an event bus designed to decouple different parts of your application while still allowing them to communicate efficiently.

You can post your data from one thread and you can subscribe for that event in other part of application. For example code check out [this link](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/48752686831/playing-around-with-otto-on-android).

Comment: Hi, Otto and EventBus (greendroid) are capable of returning you callback to a specific thread but from my knowledge they support all but returning to the caller thread. Otto (MAIN,ANY) GreenDroid(POST,MAIN,BACKGROUND,ASYNC) i need caller or SUBSCRIBER